# Unknown Provider for controller Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean

I'm quite new to the MEAN stack and are trying to incorporate a new collection to the database. I'm basing my code on this example http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/09/MEAN-Stack-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx and are already using it's code to login and register users.

I'm basically trying to do the same thing but with courses instead of users and have therefore tried to replicate how all files and controllers that affect the user collection for the course collection. All functionality works for everything involving users but I get the following error when I try to do the same for courses: **Unknown provider: CourseServiceProvider <- CourseService <- Admin.IndexController**

I have included all code that I imagine matter, but please let me know if anything else is needed.

My directory looks as the following

```
app
-account
--index.controller.js
--index.html
-admin
--index.controller.js
--index.html
-app-services
--course.service.js
--flash.service.js
--user.service.js
-home
--index.controller.js
--index.html
-app.js
-index.html
controllers
-api
--course.controller.js
--user.controller.js
-app.controller.js
-login.controller.js
-register.controller.js
services
-course.service.js
-user.service.js
views
-partials
--header
--footer
-login.ejs
-register.ejs
config.json
package.json
server.js
```

**app/admin/index.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Admin.IndexController', Controller);

    function Controller($window, CourseService, Flashservice) {
       var vm = this;

        vm.saveCourse = saveCourse;
        vm.deleteCourse = deleteCourse;

        function saveCourse(){
            //Nothing here yet
        }

        function deleteCourse(){
            //Nothing here yet
        }
    }
})();
```

**app/app-services/course.service.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('CourseService', Service);

function Service($http, $q){
    var service =  {};

    service.GetCurrent = GetCurrent;
    service.GetAll = GetAll;
    service.GetById = GetById;
    service.Create = Create;
    service.Update = Update;
    service.Delete = Delete;

    return service

   //Functions for all service.XX above, currently empty will 
look something like this(copied from app/app-services/user.service.js):
   // will user server.js who should call controllers/api/courses/method.

    function GetCurrent() {
        return $http.get('/api/users/current').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
        }    

    // private functions

    function handleSuccess(res) {
        return res.data;
    }

    function handleError(res) {
        return $q.reject(res.data);
    }
}
})();
```

**controller/course.controller**

```
var config = require('config.json');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var CourseService = require('services/course.service');

router.put('/:_id', updateCourse);
router.delete('/:_id', deleteCourse);

module.exports = router;

function updateCourse(req,res) {
    //Put code here, look at users.controller för inspo
}

function deleteCourse(req,res){
   //Put code here, look at users.controller för inspo
}
```

**services/course.service.js**

```
var config = require('config.json');
var _ = require('lodash');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Q = require('q');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');

var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-stack-registration-login-example";
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL){
    connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + "studycontrol";
}
var db = mongo.db(connectionString, { native_parser: true });

db.bind('courses');


var service = {};

service.create = create;
service.update = update;
service.delete = _delete;

module.exports = service;

function create(courseParam){
    //put code here
    createCourse();

}

function createCourse(){
    //insert course into db
}

function update(_id, courseParam){
    //put code here
   updareCourse();

function updateCourse(){
   //updaet course in database
}

function _delete(_id){
    //delete course from db
}
```

**server.js**

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ secret: config.secret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }).unless({ path: ['/api/users/authenticate', '/api/users/register'] }));


// routes
app.use('/login', require('./controllers/login.controller'));
app.use('/register', require('./controllers/register.controller'));
app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/api/users.controller'));

// make '/app' default route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.redirect('/app');
});

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

// start server
var server = app.listen(port, ipaddress);
```

**EDIT - Included app.js, below**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

   angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // default route
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home/index.html',
                controller: 'Home.IndexController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data: { activeTab: 'home' }
            })
            .state('account', {
                url: '/account',
                templateUrl: 'account/index.html',
                controller: 'Account.IndexController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data: { activeTab: 'account' }
            })
            .state('admin',{
                url: '/admin',
                templateUrl: 'admin/index.html',
                controller: 'Admin.IndexController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data:{activeTab: 'admin'}
        });
    }

    function run($http, $rootScope, $window) {
        // add JWT token as default auth header
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + $window.jwtToken;

        // update active tab on state change
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.activeTab = toState.data.activeTab;
        });
    }
    // manually bootstrap angular after the JWT token is retrieved from the server
    $(function () {
        // get JWT token from server
        $.get('/app/token', function (token) {
            window.jwtToken = token;

            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Is your application single page ? If not are you sure in the admin index.html you're loading the javascript file that contains the definition of CourseService ?

Comment: It is single-page once you are logged in. admin/index.html is rendered as part of app/index.html. In app/index.html both app-services/course.service.js and admin/index.controller.js are loaded @Walfrat

Comment: The message state the opposite, this can happens only of 2 ways : a syntax error on the service file make the file unparsed and the rest execute, unable to find the said service, or the service is not included.